# titanium mobile: display rightButton or rightView in Map Annotation in Android issue

Tags: titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Hello friends,

I am facing an issue in map-pin in Titanium Development and in map annotations I set and leftView and rightButton and also its work fine in iPhone but in android its not display rightButton and also try rightView but its not display in android so please give me idea about it.

```
var annotationParams = {
                        latitude:currentWindow.lat,
                        longitude:currentWindow.longi,
                        title:currentWindow.name,//"Atlanta, GA",
                        pincolor: isAndroid ? "orange" : Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
                        animate:true,
                        myid:1,
                        leftView: Titanium.UI.createImageView
                        ({
                            image: currentWindow.photo,
                            height: 30,
                            width: 50
                        }),
                     //rightView: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DISCLOSURE
                       rightButton: path +'/Images/fav.png'
                       };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your path might be causing the issue did you see any error logs in your titanium builder ?

Comment: rightButton should work, remove the extra params of pin and see if it works?

Comment: please online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav